# JTextPane Insert Icon Troubleshooting

Tags: java, swing, icons, awt, jtextpane

```
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event) {
    //Add images depending on selection.
    String selection = navigation.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString();
    if (selection == "Sigma") {
        try {
            Style style = document.addStyle("StyleName", null);
            StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon("sigma.png"));
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), "ignored text", style);
        } catch (BadLocationException e){

        }
    }

}
```

Hey all, so I've debugged everything and everything is working correctly except for the ACTUAL INSERTION of the icon.

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working? I have a try and catch statement, yet it still seems to fail on me.

**PS**: Don't ask for more code, my code compiles perfectly without this code. document is a global variable, and, I used styling to insert the icon (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"Don't ask for more code,"*  Don't tell me what to do.  *"my code compiles perfectly without this code."*  Maybe, but the snippet doesn't. 2) Don't ignore exceptions.

Comment: Okay I see, I'll keep that in mind. Is there any way to upload java files?

Comment: The same way you would 'upload' a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one problem:

```
selection == "Sigma"
```

that's not how you compare strings, change it to:

```
"Sigma".equals(selection)
```

Also don't swallow the exception:

```
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    //do something here
    e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

Comment: Both of those give me errors.
.equals function gives me a ")" expected error.

Comment: do e(dot)printSt... and add one more ")". The first one is a typo and the second one is a syntax error.

Comment: I did e.printStacktrace, not .eprintStacktrace (sorry for the typo), my hands are cold just went for a cigarette.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that was actually a typo on my side. The "T" is capital.

Comment: Thank you! but, it's still not inserting the icon into the JTextPane.
Any clue as to why it does that? I'm not getting errors though.